# "Final" Scheme REPL definitions: how to save them?

Tags: scheme

Is there a way to show and save all "final" definitions entered into a Scheme REPL into a text file?

Say, if I have defined in the REPL:

```
    (define (increase x) (+ 1 x))
    (define (multbytwo x) (* 3 x)) ; let us say this was an error
    (define (multbytwo x) (* 2 x))
```

I want to save this into an .scm-file with the content:

```
    (define (increase x) (+ 1 x))
    (define (multbytwo x) (* 2 x))
```

- i.e. the multbytwo function that got defined erraneously shall be "forgotten" due to re-definition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of. There is however many Lisps that can [save it's image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960140/have-some-way-to-save-the-repl-state-of-common-lisp-or-scheme) so that you can start up with all definitions. You won't be able to actually see the definitions though.

I would have kept my definitions in a file (or in the IDE like in DrRacket) and started the repl with loading that file. When changing definition you copy/past it back to your definition file when you're satisfied.

Alternatively, you could make a small REPL:

```
;; These are outside in case we break out of the REPL
(define env '())
(define (print-env)
  (newline)
  (for-each (lambda (x) (display (cdr x)) (newline)) env)
  (newline))

(define (repl)
  (define (define? expr)
    (and (pair? expr)
         (or (eq? 'define (car expr))
             (eq? 'set! (car expr)))))

  (define (define-name expr)
    (if (pair? (cadr expr))
        (caadr expr)
        (cadr expr)))

  (define (extend-env name expr)
    (let ((found (assq name env)))
      (if found
          (set-cdr! (car found) expr)
          (set! env (cons (cons name expr) env)))))

  (let ((expr (read)))
    (if (define? expr)
        (let ((name (define-name expr)))
          (eval expr (interaction-environment))
          (extend-env name expr)
          (repl))
        (let ()
              (display (eval expr (interaction-environment)))
              (newline)
              (repl)))))

(display "Outer REPL: If an error occurs, rerun with (repl)\nIn both REPL and outside yo may print definitions by calling (print-env)\n")
(repl)
```

This one is very crude. At the very first error it will exit the loop. In andoutside repl however, you may print the definitions by running (print-env).